# Update .Rd of my Package

Tags: r, package

What is the best way to update .Rd files for my new functions of my package ?

I added a function to my R script and create a .Rd file to explain this function but when I rebuilt my package with :

```
install("CAPepitesPRO",dependencies = T)
library(CAPepitesPRO)
```

The pkg compilation works fine :

```
installing help indices
  converting help for package 'mypkg'
    finding HTML links ... fini
    mypkg-package                    html  
    func1                html  
    func2                html  
    func3                html 
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
*** arch - i386
*** arch - x64
* DONE (mypkg)
In R CMD INSTALL
```

but when I try to print the help of func3 whith ?func3 I have this error :

```
No documentation for ‘func3’ in specified packages and libraries:
you could try ‘??func3’
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should run the following

```
document("yourpath/CAPepitesPRO")
```

before the following

```
install("CAPepitesPRO",dependencies = T)
```

Comment: I deleted the file NAMESPACE and run :
`document("yourpath/mypkg")`
`install("mypkg",dependencies = T) ` but I have the same message `No documentation for ‘func3’ in specified packages and libraries:`

Comment: Just to make sure, have you changed "yourpath" to your package directory?

Comment: Also, do you see the line export(func3) in your NAMESPACE file?

Comment: No in the new NAMESPACE file I have only this : `# Generated by roxygen2: do not edit by hand`

Comment: follow the instructions written [here](https://hilaryparker.com/2014/04/29/writing-an-r-package-from-scratch/) it takes 10 minutes or so.. You are probably missing an `@export` line at the end of your documentation.

Comment: Is there any other possibilities to use roxygen ? I try to add all names of my functions in NAMESPACE but it doesn't work ...
`export(func1,func2,func3)`

Comment: You shouldn't edit your namespace and description files manually, roxygen does that for you. You just add documentation code above your R functions and that's it.    I don't know if export works that way. Just start from scratch, do what the tutorial says, don't miss out any point, it works.